# How to load object after saving with encodeWithCoder?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

**EDIT_002:** Further rewrite: if I save using the method below how would the method to load it back in look? (moons is an NSMutableArray of NSNumbers)

```
// ------------------------------------------------------------------- **
// METHOD_002
// ------------------------------------------------------------------- **

-(void)saveMoons:(NSString *)savePath {
    NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:data];
    [moons encodeWithCoder:archiver];
    [archiver finishEncoding];
    [data writeToFile:savePath atomically:YES];

    [archiver release];
    [data release];
}
```

gary

Comment: What is wrong with what you have now? Personally, I prefer your simple version. The only reason to do the not-simple version is if you had to do something special or whatever to the objects (or create a non-standard file format).

Comment: Simpler one is fine for what I need, I was just interested. I might have have an idea what I did wrong, I will have a quick look and make an edit with what I find ...

Comment: Yeah, the only thing that I can see that would be an issue is 1) if moons is not a property or is not a retain property; or 2) if loadPath is somehow an incorrect path (i.e., not the same as savePath was).

Comment: I am now stating to think that I don't actually want to be using encodeWithCoder, its a bit like initWithCoder in that I should not need to call it. Just thinking out loud, but I am probbaly going to be better off using either the NSKeyedArchiver class methods or encode/decode forKey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it, my problem was that I was using ...

```
[moons encodeWithCoder:archiver];
```

where I should have been using ...

```
[archiver encodeObject:moons];
```

Hence the loader would look like:

```
-(void)loadMoons_V3:(NSString *)loadPath {
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:loadPath];
    NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:data];
    [self setMoons:[unarchiver decodeObject]];
    [unarchiver finishDecoding];

    [unarchiver release];
    [data release];
}
```

gary